# Search strings in text files and show in output the string, preceding one and next one (cmd.exe)

Tags: windows-command-prompt, search, full-text-search, findstr

I have a lot of big text files. And I'm searching (within cmd.exe) for a list of values in them as following:

```
findstr /i /n /g:strings.txt 1\*.* >results.txt
```

where strings.txt is the file with all the values I'm looking for and 1 is a folder where all my text files are.

There is valuable information in preceding and next strings to the one that I can find with findstr. Could you please help me writing a script to have 3 lines in results.txt for each match?

Comment: Can you use Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell. Specifically, the `-Context` parameter of the `Select-String` Cmdlet will give you the context surrounding the selected text.

```
PS C:\Users\ryan> gc .\temp.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

PS C:\Users\ryan> gc .\temp.txt | Select-String '4' -Context 3

  1
  2
  3
> 4
  5
  6
  7
```